# How to find word with hyphen?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to find words separated by a hyphen and surround them with some tag?

input

```
<root>
    text text text-with-hyphen text text    
</root>
```

required output

```
<outroot>
    text text <sometag>text-with-hyphen</sometag> text text
</outroot>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="root/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([^ ]*\-[^ ]*)+">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
     <sometag><xsl:value-of select="."/></sometag>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    text text text-with-hyphen text text
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
    text text <sometag>text-with-hyphen</sometag> text text
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the XSLT 2.0 **[`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#analyze-string)** instruction and its allowed children-instructions.

Comment: Helped a lot, plus one Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked, it works. So idea behind is create recursive iteration over entire text. And inside recursion step using XPath function `contains` detect if word (see usage of `$word`) contains hyphen:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <outroot>
            <xsl:call-template name="split-by-space">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="text()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </outroot>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="split-by-space"> <!-- mode allows distinguish another tag 'step'-->
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($str)"><!-- declare condition of recursion exit-->
        <xsl:variable name="word"> <!-- select next word -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str, ' ')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($word, '-')"> <!-- when word contains hyphen -->
                <sometag>
                <xsl:value-of select='concat(" ", $word)'/><!-- need add space-->
                </sometag>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- produce normal output -->
                <xsl:value-of select='concat(" ", $word)'/><!-- need add space-->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <!-- enter to recursion to proceed rest of str-->
        <xsl:call-template name="split-by-space">
            <xsl:with-param name="str"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($str, ' ')"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think it is works slower than suggestion about xsl:analyze-string from Dimitre

Comment: @Nawa but this impl works on any XSL implementation, impl above works only on XSLT 2 or above

Comment: @Dewfy: XSLT 1.0 is an obsolete version of XSLT 2.0. Even now XSLT 3.0 is in the works. XSLT 2.0 is "more XSLT" than XSLT 1.0. Apart from this, elegance and efficiency matter.